# PHP Help: if ($row['cDeviceRegistrationId'] > 0) { $a = 1;} echo $a;

Tags: php

I'm trying to have a "1" printed if there is a value in cDeviceRegistrationId column in the database. Here is the code:

$result is an SQL query

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
if ($row['cDeviceRegistrationId'] > 0) {
$a = 1;
}

 echo "<tr class='forum'>";
 echo "<td class='forum'>" . $row['intUserID'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td class='forum'>" . $row['cUsername'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td class='forum'>" . $row['cEmail'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td class='forum'>$a</td>";
 echo "<td class='forum'>" . $row['uCreateDate'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$a` is not overwritten if it does not meet the condition, meaning other iterations may get the value of `1` incorrectly. Here is a fix (replace your if statement):

```
$a = ($row['cDeviceRegistrationId'] > 0) ? 1 : '';
```

Comment: Instead of > 0, how do you plug in, IS NULL?

Comment: @BigMike: I believe MySQL returns a string value of "1" if `IS NULL` is true on a column, so try: `== "1"`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if( !is_null($row['cDeviceRegistrationId']) ){
    $a = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This one returns all as "1" even ones that shouldn't be